# Eigenvalues of symmetric matrix AB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> If matrices $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and matrix $AB$ is also symmetric, then show that every eigenvalue of $AB$ can be written as one eigenvalue of $A$ times one eigenvalue of $B$.

---

I tried so much but I could not find a good answer for that

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know something about co-diagonalization (or simultaneous diagonalization)?

Answer (score 3):

Hints.

1. If $A$, $B$, and $AB$ are symmetric matrices, then $AB=BA$.
2. If the linear transformations $\varphi$ and $\psi$ commute and $U$ is an eigenpace of $\varphi$ associated with $\lambda$, then $U$
   is an invariant subspace of $\psi$.
3. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ and $U$ is an eigenspace associated with $\lambda$, then $U$ an invariant subspace of $A$ and of $B$.
4. Let $U'$ be an eigenvalue subspace of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $\mu$.
   It follows from the above that $U'$ is an invariant space with respect to $B$.
5. Let $v\in U'$ be an eigenvector of $B$ associated with an eigenvalue $\nu$. Then
   $$
   \lambda v=AB(v)=A(B(v))=A(\nu v)=\nu A(v)=\nu\mu v\ 
   \Rightarrow\  \lambda=\mu\nu.
   $$